# import data from CSV to MS SQL using *.bat file

Tags: sql-server, csv, batch-file, batch-processing, loader

I have csv file with column:
id,name,value

I need to write simple Test.**bat** file (windows batch file), where I put:

server name, database, table, user and pass

and script will insert all *.csv data to my db. (something similar to SQL loader)

Comment: Hi Shnugo, thanks it works :)

Comment: BCP - it's installed with MS Management Studio? because if someone doesnt have, will not run my bat file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad BCP:

There is no system built in tool which is there by any means. But I think BCP is installed together with the SQL Server - probably not for all client's machines...

ad security:

One problem with a BCP call within a BAT-file is security... Be aware that everybody who can reach your BAT-File finds the full connection string in it. Everybody could introduce any SQL cmd from there...

ad own application

It might be easier and better in this point of view to write a tiny application in the coding laguage you like most, which does what you want. Thus it's on you to make sure, that this app exists on your client's machines. Such an app allows you to do side work like tracing a log file, show "real" error messages or do some kind of user's right management.

Answer (score 0):

ok,

by user I mean people from my team, but with are using Windows Authentication....

do you recomend to use other tools?

I have already wrote vba code to upload data(conn.Execute "insert.....), but it's not so fast as BCP.
Maybe if you have other examples as better solution please share

Comment: Hi, Please avoid posting answers which aren't answers... Better post a comment to the appropriate contribution or edit your question. Now you have a new question. You might think to close this question (with vote and/or acceptance - that's up to you) and then start a new question. Please post the VBA you use, At the end BCP itself is nothing else than a tool, running in your client's context. Any tool you create can be quite as fast...

Comment: my vba insert code:

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rcrds As ADODB.Recordset
Dim iRowNo, i As Long
Dim id, name, value As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim login,passwd,host,dbname  As String
login = ""
passwd = ""
host = ""
dbname = "
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Comment: With conn
        .ConnectionString = "driver={sql server};Server=" + host + _
                            ";Database=" + dbname + _
                            ";User ID=" + login + _
                            ";Password=" + passwd + _
                            ";Trusted_Connection=False;"
        .Open
    End With  
    
    iRowNo = 1

Comment: Do Until ws.Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        
                id = ws.Cells(iRowNo, 1)
                name = ws.Cells(iRowNo, 2)
                value = ws.Cells(iRowNo, 3)
                
                conn.Execute "insert into table_name(id, name, value)  values ('" & id & "', '" & name & "', '" & value & "')"                
                iRowNo = iRowNo + 1                
        Loop    

conn.Close